# How to use javascript google chart lib with aspnet mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a List of `Dictionary` or `Array` of `KeyValuePair` and this is how I'm doing

```
Dictionary<string, int> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        foreach (var item in GraphModel)
        {
            keyValuePairs.Add(item.ActivityName, item.TimeStamp);
        }
        var ArrayOfKey = keyValuePairs.ToArray();
```

and I'm trying to integrate the Google Chart Lib but I can't make the reference between C# and JavaScript, to pass the array inside of the chart!

```
function drawChart() {
      var array = @Model.GraphValue;

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task',  ''],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities',
        is3D: true,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use JSON.  Add the NewtonSoft.JSON nuget to your project, and then in your view where you have your js, try something like this:

```
function drawChart() {
      var array = @Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.GraphValue);
```

You can use Chrome devtools breakpoint at that line to inspect your JSON object and then adjust your code to fit.